# How to put a image below another?

Tags: css, html

I know their are a lot of similar questions, but non of those fixed my problem. How to put a image below another with x px gap? This is my code

html

```
<img src="images/2.jpg" style="position:absolute;">
<img src="images/1.png"  style="position:absolute;">
```

CSS

```
img {
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
max-width: 480px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
display: block; 

}
```

**Edit**: this is my problem https://jsfiddle.net/50crfe10/
As you can see, their are 2 images, but only 1 appear. because one is above another.

Comment: Please give us more information, this code is not enough to understand given problem?

Comment: Alright, let me edit my post. thank you

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I edited my post, i hope you will understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove position:absolute if your ok with it and also remove transform property

```css
img {
 max-width: 480px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin:20px auto;
 
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <img class="one" src="https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/s480x480/13432215_784505675021945_898862369521210510_n.png?oh=1600b007c6bc56ad2a9e72c5978166b5&oe=5802FEB3">
    <img class="two" src="https://scontent-sin.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13423946_783982808407565_3306592852780950589_n.png?oh=1131478aac319f301c563d020ed8214e&oe=57C2C4DE">
</body>
```

Comment: but i want the image at middle :/

Comment: just add margin:auto to img.

Comment: Worked thanks a lot, last question. How to leave some space between two images?

Comment: just change margin:auto to margin: 15px auto;

Comment: after i did it, the image is at the left not at center.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. I forgot to add auto. Really appreciated